# In Flutter, how to add a jump index to a ListView

Tags: flutter

In iOS there is a build-in way to have a jump index at the right side of a UITableView.

E.g. if the table view contains contacts you would have a jump index with the letters A-Z and if the user taps "K" the table would will automatically jump to the section with all the names that starts with a "K".

Is there something similar for Flutter ListView?

[image: Long list jump index example]

Comment: Perhaps https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/side_header_list_view, https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sticky_header_list, https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_sticky_header

Comment: It is not the headers I miss, but the right side index to jump directly to a section.

Comment: If these widgets don't provide that you'll probably need to implement that yourself for now. There might be widgets in pub.dartlang.org that I don't know about that do that though (not really up-to-date on all the community packages)

Comment: [https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/indexed_list_view](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/indexed_list_view) This might help?

Comment: The indexed_list_view package will help jump to a specific index and that is one piece of the challenge. Still missing is the UI part and finding the correct index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments and research I conclude that (right now) this is not something Flutter provides.

The building blocks for implementing it seems to be there but significant work is needed.